# App not installed due to conflict when app from play store is also installed

Tags: android, firebase-app-distribution

I'm running into an odd issue and not at all sure why.

I'm using firebase app distribution to install development-grade versions of my app and whenever I try to install a dev version of my app, it won't install claiming that the app exists already, but it doesn't.

I have the app from the store installed and upon uninstalling that, the app will *then* install but I don't understand why as both have different applicationIds.

the store version has: `com.example.myapp` & the dev version has `com.example.myapp.preview` and the app name is also different as is the version code and version name.

I don't get what they seem to share that is causing it to not allow both of them to coexist.

Not sure if this is important, but when I try to install the dev version, play protect will pop-up claiming the app is unknown and to be sure you trust it.

I'm hoping someone can steer me in a direction on solving this as I'm simply lost on what's causing the conflict.

here is the relevant gradle config:

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myppp"
        targetSdkVersion 32
        minSdkVersion 26

        versionCode verCode
        versionName "4.2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        development {
            storeFile file("../keystore/development.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("DEV_SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("DEV_SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("DEV_SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file("../keystore/debug.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("DEBUG_SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("DEBUG_SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("DEBUG_SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("../keystore/prod.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("PROD_SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("PROD_SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("PROD_SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        development {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEV"
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.preview'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.development

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with the Android Gradle plugin.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            // Makes crash reports readable
            // @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/*.kotlin_module']
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    lint {
        abortOnError true
    }
}
```

Comment: "as both have different applicationIds" -- the symptoms suggest that this is not working the way that you expect. Are you sure that the application IDs are set up the way that you are expecting?

Comment: I believe so yes, I installed an app to see the app id on the phone and can confirm they both have the ids I'm expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered my issue, it appears I was reusing the same file provider identifier, I made that more dependent on the application id and now I'm able to install the dev app alongside my store version.

I also has add product flavors as I saw a few SO answers claim that's a better way to go about what I was looking to do.